# wget timestamp alternatives

Tags: linux, bash, wget, timestamp

I have a script that works in a loop and checks for mysqlbackup copies on another server. 
couple of times a day wget downloads the file even though no change has been made.

what I've tried is using 
`--timestamping`
and
`--timestamping --no-use-server-timestamps`

Comment: OK, that's what you've done, what do you _want_ to do? Do you want to download a file only if it is newer than the local copy?

Comment: yes. i want to download a file only if it's newer

Answer (score 1):

rsync will get you what you need. It's mostly used to make delta backups, but what's important (for you) is that it can be used to only transfer a file or file(s) when the remote copy has been changed. [rsync](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-use-rsync-transfer-mirror-files-directories.html)

From the wget manual:

> The time-stamping in GNU Wget is turned on using ‘--timestamping’
>   (‘-N’) option, or through timestamping = on directive in .wgetrc. With
>   this option, for each file it intends to download, Wget will check
>   whether a local file of the same name exists. If it does, and the
>   remote file is not newer, Wget will not download it.
>
> If the local file does not exist, or the sizes of the files do not
>   match, Wget will download the remote file no matter what the
>   time-stamps say.

It should be doing what you're asking it to... right?

Comment: the same way you could use scp. i'm searching a way do it with 'wget' like method

Comment: @lan, how can i ignore the "size match"?

Comment: There is no way. wget is fine but it has built-in limitations. Why are you resisting rsync? Resistance is futile. :)